# Convert elements before pasting in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using CKEditor with ACF. This is works fine and filters out the elements I don't want. I also elected to use `<span>`s for bold, italics, and underline by adding the following items to CKEditor's config:

```
...
coreStyles_bold: {
    element: 'span',
    overrides: 'strong',
    attributes: {'style': 'font-weight: bold;'}
},
coreStyles_italic: {
    element: 'span',
    overrides: 'em',
    attributes: {'style': 'font-style: italic;'}
},
coreStyles_underline: {
    element: 'span',
    overrides: 'u',
    attributes: {'style': 'text-decoration: underline;'}
}
...
```

For those that are interested, here is my ACF configuration:

```
extraAllowedContent: '' +
    'p{font-weight,font-style,text-decoration,text-align};' +
    'a[!href];' +
    'span{font-weight,font-style,text-decoration,text-align};' +
    'br ul ol;' +
    'li{font-weight,font-style,text-decoration,text-align};' +
    'gallery vid attachment[trix-id](*);' +
    'table tr td th;' +
    'div(trix-inserting,attachment,break)[contenteditable]'
```

(a lot of this is specific to this particular app, but I'm posting it here to show that ACF is configured correctly)

The problem I have is when **bold** text is copied, it often is structured like this:

```
<b>My text</b>
```

However, my ACF configuration doesn't allow the `<b>` tag, and so the tag gets removed, therefore pasting non-bold text.

What I'd like is some way to scan through all the elements being pasted (before ACF is fired), and change the `<b>`, `<strong>`, `<em>`, `<u>`, `<i>` and whatever other bold, italic and underline tags there are to the styles shown in the config (above).

How can I do this?

Comment: Try avoiding getting the html tags if content is copied. Add this in your configuration `paste_remove_styles: true`

Comment: @raveenanigam can you explain this a bit more? I can't find any documentation on paste_remove_styles

Comment: `CKEDITOR.config.forcePasteAsPlainText` 
this might help you : http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html

Comment: @raveenanigam I don't want to paste as plain text though :) I want to keep the formatting